# How to parse a date string containing weekday name?

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like to parse date: `"wednesday 02 2000"` so the `DateTime` object I get will be set to the first wednesday of February 2000. Unfortunately the `ParseExact` method doesn't work that way. Is this is possible to achieve in C# by an existing method?

```
  String s1 = "tuesday 02 2000";
  String s2 = "wednesday 02 2000";
  String format = "dddd MM yyyy";
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(s1, format, new CultureInfo("en-US")));//doesn't throw an exception because tuesday was 01.02.2000
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(s2, format, null));//throws an exception because wednsday was 02.02.2000
```

I know solution for this problem: setting DateTime to the 1.02.2000 and then adding days until i reach wednesday, but I am not happy with that soluton.

```
while (date.DayOfWeek != day) {
         date = date.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: Wednsday is not spelled correctly.

Comment: @krillgar Now it is, fortunately still doesn't work : )

Comment: @Yoda I think your existing solution is the only workable one. Besides, for any given day of the week, the maximum number of iterations is 7.